# How show size in KB in dired mode?

Tags: dired

Windows 10 (64 bit), Emacs 25.1, package dired+.

In dired mode files size show in bytes. But I want to show in KB.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Try using **`h`** among your **`dired-listing-switches`** - e.g., `-alFh`. It stands for "*human-readable*", and it shows sizes in KB etc.

But which `ls` switches are available can depend on your particular `ls` command (e.g. on your platform), so try `M-x man RET ls RET`.

Instead of, or in addition to, setting `dired-listing-switches`, you can just use a prefix arg with command `dired`, to be prompted for the `ls` switches to use for that directory listing. E.g., **`C-u C-x d`**.

---

Update 2019-06-16.  If your `ls` supports it (or if you use built-in `ls-lisp.el`, which is the case by default for MS Windows) you can use `S` (uppercase) with `h` to show and *sort by* human-readable size.

Answer (score 5):

Does `dired-listing-switches` help?  I've set mine to -alh and I get the filesizes in KB, but not the available bytes.  There might be another setting for that.

Comment: Yes, it's help. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/64156/why-in-dired-mode-dired-k-human-readable-t-not-work/64160#64160