# Why in sizes of files not show in human-readable format?

Tags: dired

Linux Mint 20

Emacs 26.3

I install packaged **dired-k**

And set this param in my init.el

```
'(dired-k-human-readable t)
```

But it not work in dired mode.

Here example
[image: Dired mode]

As you can see size of files not show like **KB/MB** (human readable)

If in shell I use

```
ls -alFH
```

The show with human readable format:

```
 alexei@alexei-nb:~/.emacs.d$ ls -alFh
total 168K
drwx------  8 alexei alexei  12K Mar 27 18:22 ./
drwxrwxr-x 55 alexei alexei 4.0K Mar 27 17:54 ../
drwx------  2 alexei alexei 4.0K Mar 27 19:55 auto-save-list/
-rw-rw-r--  1 alexei alexei  11K Mar 25 23:37 bookmarks
drwxr-xr-x  2 alexei alexei 4.0K Mar 27 18:31 custom/
-rw-r--r--  1 alexei alexei 6.2K Mar 27 19:54 dired-history
drwxr-xr-x 62 alexei alexei 4.0K Mar 27 18:00 elpa/
drwx------  2 alexei alexei 4.0K Mar 16 23:42 eshell/
drwxr-xr-x  9 alexei alexei 4.0K Mar 27 19:54 .git/
-rw-r--r--  1 alexei alexei  341 Mar 19 21:21 .gitignore
-rw-------  1 alexei alexei 8.6K Mar 27 19:54 history
-rw-rw-r--  1 alexei alexei  62K Mar 27 19:54 ido.last
-rw-rw-r--  1 alexei alexei 8.6K Mar 27 19:54 init.el
-rw-r--r--  1 alexei alexei   50 Mar 19 21:18 README.md
-rw-------  1 alexei alexei 1.6K Mar 27 19:54 recentf
```

But why it's not work in dired mode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dried+, Dired-K. Available space in KB/MB?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36401/dried-dired-k-available-space-in-kb-mb)

Comment: If what you posted is actually the line in your init file, the problem is that there's a **quote** `'` before the code you meant to have in the file. `'(some stuff)` is just data, it does nothing when executed. (It evaluates to a list, which is ignored because it's at the top level in a file.) Remove the quote so that the line is code that is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.
I customize **dired-listing-switches**.

So here in init.el file:

```
'(dired-listing-switches "-alFh")
```

And in dired mode show size in human readable format:

[image: Dired mode in human readable format]

Comment: I think your answer has nothing to do with `dired-k` (switch `h` suffices), which means that your question also has nothing to do with `dired-k`. Please edit the question to reflect this, so other users whom this Q&A might help can more easily find it.